# wp_query in page childs and category childs

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to alter the search results in some part of a Wordpress website.

Les results should be childs of pages 425 or 2064, OR childs of categories 9 or 63.

I don't think it's possible with `wp_query`. Maybe something like :

```
global $wp_query;

$args = array(
    's' => $s,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_parent__in' => array( 425, 2064 ),
    'category__in' => array( 9, 63 ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I filtered the posts

```
<?php
// filtered content
$first_parent_page = 425;
$second_parent_page = 2064;
$first_parent_cat = 9;
$second_parent_cat = 63;
if (
    // in pages and sub-pages
    $post->post_parent==$first_parent_page || $post->post_parent==$second_parent_page
    // in cat
    || in_category( [$first_parent_cat,$second_parent_cat] )
    // in sub-cat
    || (get_term_children($first_parent_cat,'category') && in_category((get_term_children($first_parent_cat,'category'))))
    || (get_term_children($second_parent_cat,'category') && in_category((get_term_children($second_parent_cat,'category'))))
) { ?>
```